# Removing background loading gif after slider loaded

Tags: jquery, css, slider, gif

Im setting up a simple loading gif to act as a place holder while the slider images are loading, ive got it setup and working fine, but the slider images fade to white between each image, so every time they fade you can see the loading gif spinning.

Im trying to work out a way to hide it once the images have loaded, but i just cant see how to do it, ive tried to push it right to the back using `z-index: -1000;` but that still didnt work, any ideas how i could accomplish this ?

Ive made a jsfiddle of the slider running here - http://jsfiddle.net/k4z7U/1/

Comment: You really want the fade-to-white? Usually people ask how to get rid of that "white" issue...

Comment: Dosnt really bother me either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
$('.loading-gif').remove();
```

In the `ready` function.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtzcZ/